# EF Code-First from existing db add models into existing DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So maybe this is a stupid question, because I know that when creating a Code-first model from an existing database, Visual Studio will create a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and add the models in a new DbContext.

I am using Microsoft Identity in my project, hence there is already a `ApplicationDbContext` (IdentityDbContext). I think just having all my models in a single DbContext would be easier to handle. I am generating my code-first models from an existing database.

But Is there a way such that the generated models add up into the already existing DbContext (In this case, the IdentityDbContext?)

I have like, many models, so currently I am compelled to add each of them into existing `ApplicationDbContext` manually, and remove from the created DbContext.

Comment: why don't you just inherit from the ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Good Idea! But I want all models in **one single** `DbContext` :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is no way to add the generated models objects to the existing DbContext automatically. You need to add them manually.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")            
    {

    }

    //Add your Model objects here, You can copy them from automatically generated DbContext
    public virtual DbSet<ModelObjectName> PropertyName { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Copy the modelBuilder configuration here from automatically generated DbContext here

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that works:

1. Mark your `ApplicationDbContext` class as partial:

   ```
   public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
            //unchanged
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           //unchanged
       }
   }
   ```
2. Do the same with your custom Data model class, and remove the inheritance from `DbContext`. Also, remove constructor form it and change the `OnModelCreating` into a regular private method with some different name. Keep the rest unchanged.

   ```
   public partial class MyDataModels
   {

           //unchanged

       private void OnModelCreating2(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           //unchanged
       }
   }
   ```
3. Refactor (*Ctrl + R + R : default shortcut*) name of your Data model class, and change it to `ApplicationDbContext`. Visual Studio might give you a conflict warning during refactoring, ignore that and refactor. Finally, call `OnModelCreating2()` from `OnModelCreating()` method of `ApplicationDbContext` class.

   ```
   public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
            //unchanged
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           //unchanged

           OnModelCreating2(modelBuilder);
       }
   }
   ```

Another nice approach suggested by @DevilSuichiro is to simply inherit your Data model class from `ApplicationDbContext`.

Cheers!